# SQL Server - flag column for record with lowest value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have following table:

```
ID | Number | ... |
1  | 100    | ... |
1  | 200    | ... |
2  | 400    | ... |
2  | 300    | ... |
2  | 500    | ... |
3  | 600    | ... |
```

I am trying to add a column that shows me which record holds the lowest `Number` value, grouped by ID.

So my result would be:

```
ID | Number | ... | IsLowest
1  | 100    | ... | 1
1  | 200    | ... | 0
2  | 400    | ... | 0
2  | 300    | ... | 1 
2  | 500    | ... | 0
3  | 600    | ... | 1
```

Any suggestions/Ideas?

Comment: use Row_Number function

Comment: Do you want to update the isLowest column value or want to insert the value in it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `min` window function.

```
select id,number,
case when min(number) over(partition by id) = number then 1 else 0 end is_lowest
from t
```